# How to sum this query set element in Django template?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a function to view report:

```
def view_report(request):
    a = Bill.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('report.html', {'a':a}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

There's a attribute called price which has numeric elements. I want to sum all the prices and show as one number in Django template:

```
{% for i in a %}

{{ i.price }}

{% endfor %}
```

This simply returns all the prices. I want to sum all those prices and show as one. I tried using `{{  i.price|sum }}` which didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't do that in the template. Use the [aggregation API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/aggregation/) in your view:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
total_price = Bill.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('price'))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I am getting the answer in dictionary format:{'price__sum': 89}. I only want value not the key. How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Just use normal dictionary access: `total_price['price__sum']`, or in the template `{{ total_price.price__sum }}`.

Comment: Aggregation API URL is outdated. New link = https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/